# Vertical Scroll bar not working in IE8/IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is to put a vertical scroll bar to the tbody of a table.I have achieved it using

```
<tbody style='
    display:block;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    max-height:200px;
    width:100%;
'>
```

This works fine in Chrome,FF,IE10/IE11.

But in IE8/IE9 i could not see the vertical scroll bar.With keeping `float:left` , i could see a vertical scroll bar,but the thead and tbody are misaligned leaving a lot of space between the scroll bar and the tbody tr's.

There are a lot of such questions in stackoverflow, but none could help me.Please advice.

Comment: You cannot achieve that cross-browser using CSS only.

Comment: Please let me know how to achieve the result

Comment: http://datatables.net

Comment: It works only with duplicating the tables and stacking both tables on top of each other, one setting `tbody` to `display: none`, the other setting `thead` to `display: none`. That's the only way to wrap the `tbody` in a `div` which can be styled as you require. Additional magic is required to make sure column widths match.

Comment: i will give a try bro..and also how is your last comment related to datatables.

Comment: datatables does all that for you, and much more, if desired.

Comment: actually i am not that familiar with the datatables. What property do i need to add in the datatable?

Comment: Is the documentation unavailable to you? https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183770/discussion-between-pavan-ghantasala-and-connexo).